# How to use case in pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, plsql

I want to create a pivot of working hour by department and date.
I had a sql like 
`select department,sum(workinghours),date group by department,date.`
then I write a pivot sql

```
select * from(
     select department,sum(workinghours) as hours,date group by department,date
        )as RC
    PIVOT
    (
        sum(hours) for date 
    )as P
```

but this return lots of null value. so I update the pivot to

```
select * from(
         select department,sum(workinghours) as hours,date group by department,date
            )as RC
        PIVOT
        (
            (case when sum(hours) is null then 0 else sum(hours) end) for date 
        )as P
```

then it has error.
I don't understand why, anyone can help?Thx.

Comment: sample data and expected output is helpful to guide properly , so please share sample data and expected output

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace your `null` with some specific values in `sum`. As I have replaced 0 instead of `null`:

```
create table #t
(
Id int identity (1,1),
Department varchar (100),
WorkingHours int  ,
Date datetime
)

Insert into #t (Department,WorkingHours,Date)
Select '1','10',GETDATE ()-1

Insert into #t (Department,WorkingHours,Date)
Select '1','20',GETDATE ()-1
Insert into #t (Department,WorkingHours,Date)
Select '1',null,GETDATE ()

select * from #t

select * from(
         select department,sum(ISNULL(workinghours,0)) as hours,
         cast (Year(date) as varchar) date 
         from #t
         group by department,date
            )as RC
        PIVOT
        (
            sum(hours ) for date  IN ([2018])
        )as P
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below with case when inside sum :

```
select * from(
         select department,sum(workinghours) as hours,date group by department,date
            )as RC
        PIVOT
        (
            sum(case when hours is null then 0 else hours end) for date 
        )as P
```